# Obtener elementos de un Objeto Json

Tags: json, array

Que tal comunidad espero me puedan ayudar. Tengo un arreglo de objetos Json como este.

```
[
{"titulo": "La caida de los gigantes", "autor": "Ken Follet"}, 
{"titulo": "Aqueron", "autor": "Sherrilyn Kenyon"},
{
    "titulo": "Los hombres que no amaban a las mujeres", 
    "autor": "Stieg Larsson"
}
```

]

Del cual obtengo de mi consulta de base de datos. Hasta ahora he podido acceder a mis propiedades como Titulo y nombre a través de este código.

```
 if (data != '') {
       valores = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
       if (valores.length > 0) {
           for (aux in valores[0])
               atributos.push(aux);                  
       }

           for (i = 0; i < atributos.length; i++) {
               resultadoAtributos += atributos[i] + " ";
           }
```

Con esto he podido asignarle el nombre de mis columnas de mi control (jqxGrid).

Lo que necesito hacer ahora es obtener el nombre del titulo y el autor para poder llenar mi grid ya que solo me muestra el nombre de mis columnas. Alguien sabe como puedo lograr esto por medio de un for sin tener que acceder a sus atributos como Titulo o Autor de forma directa. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bienvenido a la Comunicad,

Recuerda que para poder iterar JSON la forma más correcta es usando la estructura for,

```
`for(var clave in json){
  //datos
 }`
```

Para este ejemplo sería de la siguiente forma,

```js
var json = [{'titulo':'La caida de los gigantes','autor':'Ken Follet'},{'titulo':'Aqueron','autor':'Sherrilyn Kenyon'},{'titulo':'Los hombres que no amaban a las mujeres','autor':'Stieg Larsson'}];

var d = JSON.stringify(json);
for(var clave in json) { 
  //console.log(clave)
  console.log(json[clave]['autor']);
  //console.log(json[clave]['titulo']);  
}
```

En este claso como tenemos varios títulos, le tenemos que pasar la clave, y el índice que necesitamos extraer, espero te sirve, saludos.